# Converting aspx with gis / Hebrew to PDF

Tags: asp.net, pdf, gis, data-conversion

I'm trying to to convert aspx pages to PDF.
The two main issues I've encountered are:

1. Some of those pages contains gis elements (mostly google maps, but some may be municipal maps). When the user changes their position - I want it to be converted properly. Right now I couldn't event convert their default position to pdf.
2. The text is in Hebrew and I'm having hard time converting it.

I've tried using jsPDF - used their addHTML function and looked at their runner example (which is using iframe - but doesn't seem to work on explorer, or with maps)

Does anyone have any other idea as to how I can convert this? Maybe convert the page to jpeg and then to convert it?

If you have working samples - that would be excellent.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using IECapt (http://iecapt.sourceforge.net/) to convert it to JPEG and then convert it from JPEG to PDF.

for example:
IECapt --url=http://www.page_you_want_to_render.org/ --out=the_render.jpeg

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I send him a url - in regards to the gis maps - will it be able to capture the user's changes? (if the user zooms in / out of the map and then wants to convert it - will it show the modified map or the default one?)

Comment: probably not, it will get only from the url